# My calculation keeps adding 1 every time instead of actually calculating the right number

Tags: c#

So I have to make a program that prints how many times it has to make a certain calculation. However, when I print the result, I seem to be getting 16000 numbers that just add +1 every new time. My question is how to fix this. I have no idea...

Thank you for your help!

My code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a = 0;
        double b = 0;
        double distance = 0;
        int i = 1;
        for (double x = -2; x < 2; x = x+0.01)
        {
            for (double y = -2; y < 2; y = y+ 0.01)
            {
                while(distance <= 2 || i < 100)
                {
                    a = a * a - b * b + x;
                    b = 2 * a * b + y;
                    double a2b2 = Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2);
                    distance = Math.Sqrt(a2b2);
                    i++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are printing `i` and that's whats happening to `i` in your code.

Comment: yes I know, i is the amount of calculations, but he should create a new calculation for every new x and every new y

Comment: So print out distance along with i to see what the calculations really are.

Comment: Do you want to print something else? Like `distance`?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger? Or considered adding logging of `distance`, `a`, and `b` in each iteration?

Comment: `distance` is the same every time I print it

Comment: I'm suspicious that `a`, `b`, `distance` and `i` are all initialized outside of any loops but only changed deep in the inner loop - and that the conditions for terminating the inner `while` loop will remain in effect for all subsequent iterations. Unclear what you're trying to do here but the logic seems flawed based on that.

Comment: okay so `a` and `b` should always start as 0. The distance from 0 to 0 is also that and should only be changed inside the loop and `i` should start at 0 again every time you start the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to plot a fractal of some description - I haven't checked the maths, but it reminds me of code I've used to generate Mandelbrot set images before now.

The problem is that you should be creating an independent calculation for each point - but you're maintaining the state of `a`, `b`, `i` and `distance` between points. That means once `distance` has become greater than 2 and `i` is greater than 100, you'll *never* get into the inside of the `while` loop. Just move the declaration and initialization of those variables to *inside* your inner `for` loop.

Additionally, the conditions for your `while` loop should be ANDed together rather than ORed together, assuming that the idea is to effectively limit it to 100 iterations per point.

```
for (double x = -2; x < 2; x += 0.01)
{
    for (double y = -2; y < 2; y += 0.01)
    {
        // Initialize the local variables here, as they're meant to be independent for each point.
        double a = 0;
        double b = 0;
        double distance = 0;
        int i = 1;

        while (distance <= 2 && i < 100)
        {
            a = a * a - b * b + x;
            b = 2 * a * b + y;
            double a2b2 = Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2);
            distance = Math.Sqrt(a2b2);
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The double type means floating point type. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). This type is not the right numeric type for precise addition like you use. Instead of that use decimal type.

Comment: No, I suspect `double` is absolutely fine for the use case here. (It's certainly what I've used for very similar situations, plotting the Mandelbrot set.) This isn't the problem.